# WAMP server directories within web directory(www) are not accessible

Tags: wamp, wampserver

The problem I am facing is that I just upgraded to Win 7 64-bit and installed Wamp server with VC++ and it works fine.

But I can't access subdirectories in the web directory (C:\wamp\www), I can access the files although.

Please guide me through.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 or this on the wampserver forum site http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482

Answer (score 0):

It is now strongly advised that you create Virtual Hosts for all your project, even those that you store in the \wamp\www\project1 folder structure.

WampServer now assumes that you have done this, and that is why you get this issue.

Here is a previous answer [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)